# How to add <taglib> elements to web.xml with Netbeans7.0?

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

I want add JSTL taglib into my jsp page. I used TLD (tag lib descriptor), but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<taglib xml......./java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeeversion="2.1">

<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<uri>/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-impl-1.2.jar</uri>

</taglib>
```

and imported it like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the proper way to install and use JSTL. Remove the loose TLD files. Remove any edits you made in `web.xml`. Ignore and blacklist all tutorials and other online resources which told you to do so.

The proper way is:

- Investigate if target container already ships with JSTL bundled. Simple containers like Tomcat, Jetty, etc don't. You need to drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp (which is covered by webapp's default runtime classpath) **or** in the (shared) classpath of the container. Nothing else needs to be done. Do not extract the JAR file nor create TLD files or something. More fledged containers like Glassfish, JBoss AS, etc already ships with JSTL bundled. In this case, you don't need to download anything nor change the classpath.
- Read the [JSTL taglib documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). You would like to use the JSTL core library. Click on the [JSTL core](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) link in the taglib documentation. Read the "standard syntax" part how to properly declare in in a JSP file. It reads like

  ```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  ```

  *(note the `/jsp` part in the taglib URI!)*

That's all.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thanks, i left the /jsp part in my taglib URI.